# Can we custom our own template in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart, templates

Initially Flutter having template that gives the default folder structure for our Flutter application.

By using `flutter create -t skeleton project_name, we can create the skeleton template.

In the same way can we custom our template with customized folder structure?

e.g. `flutter create -t own_template project_name`

it would be really helpful if found approach for it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, flutter has this package can satisfy your wish [mason](https://pub.dev/packages/mason)

It maybe take you some time to learn and implement it but after you know how to use it, it really make your life easier

Some tutorial you can found here :
[video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4PTjA6tpTU) ,  [document](https://github.com/felangel/mason/tree/master/packages/mason_cli)